# Bash: is there a way to execute a command if another command times out?

Tags: bash, timeout

I need to run a command with the timeout function, so that if it is not executed in x time, then the script shall start from the beginning, otherwise it can proceed and execute other commands. Can I do that?

I already tried to use case, but it works as long as I use one, if use two cases it gives me an error. Does anybody know how to do it with timeout? Maybe using an user-defined signal like -s USR1, but I don't know how to set that up and if I can execute a command with a signal :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `some_command` completes within 10 seconds, this will continue on with the rest of the script.  If `some_command` times out, then it is repeated until it doesn't time out:

```
while timeout 10 some_command; [ $? -eq 124 ]
do
   :
done
echo "Continuing on with script"
```

#### How it works

If a command times out, then, by default, `timeout` exits with code 124.  We can use this to test whether the command timed out and, hence, whether it needs to be repeated.  In more detail:

- `while timeout 10 some_command; [ $? -eq 124 ]; do`

  This starts a `while loop` by executing `some_command` with a 10 second timeout and then testing whether the exit code from `timeout` is 124 or not.  If it is 124, then the while-loop repeats.
- `:`

  The command `:` is a no-op.  We don't need any command within the body of the `while` loop, we use this command.
- `done`

  This marks the end of the `while` loop.

#### Special case: ill-behaved commands

This assumes that some_command responds responsibly to the TERM signal.  If it doesn't, the exit code will be 128+9 instead of 124.

#### Documentation

From `man timeout`:

> If the command times out, and --preserve-status is not set, then
>   exit  with  status  124.   Otherwise, exit with the status of COMMAND.
>   If no signal is   specified, send the TERM signal upon timeout.  The
>   TERM  signal  kills  any   process  that  does not block or catch that
>   signal.  It may be necessary to   use the KILL (9) signal, since this
>   signal cannot be caught, in which  case
>    the exit status is 128+9 rather than 124.

Comment: But can you explain why that value? Why 124? Is that universal?

Comment: @D.Appresti Yes, 124 is "universal."  I just added some explanation to the answer.  (You may need to reload the page to see it.)